# How to set rows per partition cache

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

Is there way in Phantom DSL to specify number of rows cached per partition? I can do:

> .create.ifNotExists().`with`(caching eqs Cache.RowsOnly())

but i cant find way how to specify caching condition like: ALL Keys + 500 rows per partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table
  .create.ifNotExists()
  .with(
    caching eqs Cache.RowsOnly().rows_per_partition(CacheStrategies.ALL)
  )
```